# Accessing data in stored nested layers of arrays and hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have the following data structure that stores data in a combination of arrays and hashes:

```
$data = [
          {
            'foo' => {
                       'lang' => 'en',
                       'contact' => [
                                      {
                                        'email' => 'foo@example.org'
                                      },
                                      {
                                        'phone' => '2125551212'
                                      }
                                    ],
                       'browser' => 'firefox'
                     }
          },
          {
            'bar' => {
                       'lang' => 'fr',
                       'contact' => [
                                      {
                                        'email' => 'bar@example.com'
                                      },
                                      {
                                        'phone' => '9125551212'
                                      }
                                    ],
                       'browser' => 'lynx'
                     }
          }
        ];
```

How can I get a string that contains bar's email?
Additional data might be present, so accessing anything using a hard coded array index would not work.

I did experiment using various combinations of grep, but did not have that much success with it due to the way the data is nested.

Comment: Your data allows multiple 'bar' with each having multiple 'email'. Is this really what you want? You may want to rethink that.

Comment: I didn't come up with it, it is the result of parsing JSON created by some other code that I have no control over. There shouldn't be any duplicate values, but as a precaution I will just use the first occurrence if there are.

Answer (score 4):

First, severely punish whoever created that structure. There might be something more in your real data, but I've seen such clumsy structures in real life too.

Walk the data structure to get to the contact. First, find the hashes that have the key you want:

```
my $key = 'bar';
my @hashes =
    map { exists $_->{$key} ? $_->{$key} : () } $data->@*;
```

Now it's a bit trickier because that `$contact` is an array of hashes where only one (or maybe less than all) of the hashes has what you need. You need to check each of those hashes, so you have to flatten that list (which makes this really annoying):

```
my @contact_hashes =
    map { exists $_->{contact} ? $_->{contact}->@* : ()  }
    @hashes;
```

That's all the hashes with an `email` key. Now extract the values:

```
my @email = map { $_->{email} } @contact_hashes;
```

You can put that together in various ways to get rid of the temporary values:

```
my @email =
    map { exists $_->{email} ? $_->{email} : () }
    map { exists $_->{contact} ? $_->{contact}->@* : ()  }
    map { exists $_->{$key} ? $_->{$key} : () }
    $data->@*;
```

This is the sort of stuff I cover in [Intermediate Perl](https://www.intermediateperl.com), but the [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc) is good too.

Comment: I don't think the index 1 in `$data->[1]{bar}{contact}` is known beforehand, the OP needs to find those too.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

This will find all "bars" and all their "emails"

```
no autovivification;
print
  map {
    map { $_->{email} // () }
      @{ $_->{bar}{contact} // [] }
    } @$data;
```

The module autovivification is needed to avoid destroying your data with new elements.

---

###### UPDATE

Here a short approach avoiding autovivification without dependencies to CPAN modules like `autovivification` or `Data::Diver`

```
# ------ short version
@emails =
  map { $_->{email} // () }
  map { @{ $_->{contact} // [] } }
  map { $_->{bar} // () }
  @$data;
```

or a longer version highlighting the principals behind this

```
# ------ long symmetrical version
@emails =
  map { $_->{email} // () }
  map { @$_ }
  map { $_->{contact} // () }
  map { $_->{bar} // () }
  map { @$_ }
  $data;
```

Again ... Please be aware that the structure of your data gives no guarantee that there is only one "bar" and that each "bar" has only one "email".

Hence your result-set must be an array @emails.

Better restructure your data into something straight forward and less dangerous. Especially if you need many lookups.

---